# How can I find out the address of a WebAssembly buffer and return it to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, memory-address, webassembly

I'm trying to obtain the memory address of a WebAssembly buffer and return it to Javascript, so that I can instaniate its memory as a Javascript ArrayBuffer and directly write in an array in the module's memory at the appropriate address.

The c code:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t buff[10][100];

uint64_t addr(int buffer_index){
    return (uint64_t)&buff[buffer_index];
}
```

I compile it with:

```
emcc project.c -Os -s WASM=1 -s SIDE_MODULE=1 -o project.wasm
```

The html:

```
<script>
var importObject = {
        env: {
            memoryBase: 0,
            tableBase: 0,
            setTempRet0:(x)=>{},
            memory: new WebAssembly.Memory({ initial:256 }),
            table: new WebAssembly.Table({ initial:0, element:'anyfunc' })
        }
    };

    fetch('http://localhost:9000/assets/wasm/project.wasm').then(
        response => response.arrayBuffer()
    ).then(
        bytes => WebAssembly.instantiate(bytes, importObject)
    ).then(
        results => {
            let module=results.instance
            let exports=module.exports
            let addr=exports._addr
            console.log(addr(0))
            console.log(addr(1))
            console.log(addr(2))
        }
    )
</script>
```

The result of the run:

```
project.html:21 5242880
project.html:22 5242980
project.html:23 5243080
```

This looks sane, because the buffer has 100 byte chunks, and the returned addresses are 100 bytes apart.

How can I find out where these addresses point in the module's memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your have provided the module with memory via `importObject.env.memory`. You simply have to use the offsets / addresses provided to inspect the memory allocated to your `buff` variable in your C code:

```
// create a Uint8Array as a 'view' on the module linear memory
// starting at _addr(0), and with a length of 100 elements.
var buffer = new Uint8Array(importObject.env.memory.buffer, exports._addr(0), 100);

for (var i=0; i<buffer.length; i++) {
  var foo = buffer[i];
  // do something with foo here!
}
```

You can see a more complete example in [my project that renders a Mandelbrot fractal](https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/wasm-mandelbrot).

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it has solved my problem. However instead of  the memory you have to take the view of the memory buffer, so the correct line is: `var buffer = new Uint8Array(importObject.env.memory.buffer, exports._addr(0), 100);`. I also like your project with the Mandelbrot fractal.

Comment: `(exports._addr || exports.addr)(0)` - underline is added by emcc only, llvm exports names as is.